# Unable to move files to folder in php

Tags: php, file-upload, php-7

while trying to allow users to upload images of theirs into my site, I did this

```
<li>
  <label for="pic">Image</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?=$max; ?>">
  <input type="file" name="user[pic]" id="pic">
<li>
```

And in the registration controller, I did this(after frustrated, just to make sure it upload successfully), and it dosent work…

```
$file = $_FILES['user']['pic']['name'] . time() . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '.jpeg';
        //$user['pic'] = $file;
        //$destination = 'C:/me/ijdb/Project/public/imgs/';
        $filename = 'C:\me\ijdb\Project\public\imgs\\' . $file;
        if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['user']['pic']['tmp_name']) or !copy($_FILES['user']['pic']['tmp_name'], $filename)){
            $valid = false;
            $errors[] = "Could not save file as $filename!";
        }
```

NB: just extract the image section as it dosen’t work and I thought I have to use `$_FILES['user']['pic']['tmp_name']` to extract or get the neccessary info just as plain text like `$user['username']`(will get what is in the username textarea).

Please, who can put me through how to do it?

Theform tag attribute is displayed below

```
<form id="theForm" method="post" action="" accept-charset="utf8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<li>
                    <label for="firstName">Firstname</label>
                    <input name="user[firstName]" id="firstName" type="text" value="<?=$user['email'] ?? ''?>" autofocus required>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="lastNane">Your lastname</label>
                    <input name="user[lastName]" id="lastName" type="text" value="<?=$user['lastName'] ?? ''?>">
                </li>
```

Two more fields added. I use this style so as to get the all the user input in the controller sing this short version of `$user['firstName']` will get the value of `$user[fistName']`

Comment: where's the form tags?

Comment: I only extract the file section @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: how do we know if the method is right and that you're using the proper enctype to handle files? Unless you feel that's irrelevant, then enable error reporting and see what caused your code to fail.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner form tags included now

Comment: Shouldn't that be: name="user['pic']"

Comment: @Difster that is the pattern I use for others. Maybe I should display the whole registration form

Comment: Have you checked your logs for errors?

Comment: @Difster log errors? am on local host

Comment: You have a local webserver right? If you're getting PHP errors, they will log somewhere.

Comment: I'd recommend [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/function.move-uploaded-file.php) over `copy()`

Comment: @Phil I also try using the move_upload_file() also